# programmatically trigger auth guard

Tags: angular, router, auth-guard

Is it possible to trigger `AuthGuard` within a component?

The purpose for this is if some logic fails, then it triggers the `AuthGuard` where `AuthGuard` holds the logic to navigate user until they have completed the tasks given in that page.

Comment: How authGuard is holding the path to next page. If you want to navigate you could do using `router.navigate[youraddress]`

Comment: You need to use the if conditions in case if error occur you can call the AuthGuard Service

Comment: You should redirect on your own, authguard is to protect a route

Comment: @Eldho I am trying to use the single responsibility principle, but the main reason for this is, `AuthGuard` holds the logic to direct to and store current path when user completes tasks on the other page.

Comment: @Exterminator how do you do it? treat `AuthGuard` service as normal service when we call it?

Comment: route guards are interfaces which can tell the router whether or not it should allow navigation to a requested route. https://ryanchenkie.com/angular-authentication-using-route-guards
IMHO guards should not have any logic rather than basic authentication & roles checking

Comment: Yes, you can use it or you can create a function in a service that will return value then you can use the value to redirect it or you can redirect from that function as well.